# Return value outside of node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cheerio, url-shortener

So I have this question but I cant find a solution. I am scraping my website with axios and cheerio and my url's are very big so I want to use a shortener, I found npm (node-url-shortener) and its very simple to use `shortUrl.short('https://google.com', function(err, url){
    console.log(url);
});`

but I dont want to console.log I want to store that value

```
  $(
    ".searchListing"
  ).each((index, element) => {
    const name = $(element)
      .children(".media")
      .children("a")
      .text();

    let url = $(element)
      .children(".media")
      .children("a")
      .attr("href");

    shortUrl.short(url, function(err, url) {
      return url;
    });

    console.log(??????);


    prices[index] = { name, url };
  });
```

How can I store the shortened url in my array outside of `shortUrl.short` module?

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)